# Componentes variables en Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, component

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en angular y estoy creando componentes para distintas funcionalidades. La aplicación consiste en ejercicios para resolver, y quiero crear componentes con cada una de las funcionalidades.

Voy a situar un ejemplo para que sea más fácil de entender. He creado un componente que al pintarse en html, es un ejercicio de verdadero o falso. Cada vez que lo integro, siempre aparecen las mismas preguntas, y mi intención es que esas preguntas cambien cada vez que lo integro.

He pensado en pasarle un parámetro al componente de una variable tipo objeto para que a través de ella pinte lo necesario.

Aqui el html

`<app-trueOrFalse objeto=[objeto]></app-trueOrFalse>`

Y aquí el objeto de ejemplo en typescript

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    let objeto1 :{
      "preguntas": [
        "pregunta1", "pregunta2", "pregunta3"
      ],
      "respuestas":[
        true, false, true
      ]
    }

}
```

Esta es la manera que mejor se me ha ocurrido, creando distintos objetos para los distintos TrueOrFalse que vaya creando, pero desconozco si existe una mejor manera de hacer esto.

Un saludo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías recibir parámetros en el componente que reutilizas para cambiar las preguntas de la siguiente manera:

En tu archivo .ts (del componente que vas a reutilizar) pon lo siguiente:

```
// Variable para recibir las preguntas
@Input() questions: string[];

// En el ngOnInit imprimir las preguntas que te llegan
ngOnInit(): void {
  // Las preguntas que recibes ya estarían en la variable questions
  // y podrías acceder a ellas directamente
  console.log('preguntas:', questions);
}
```

Ahora cuando llames al componente en tu archivo .html envías el listado de preguntas que deseas mostrar de la siguiente manera:

```
<app-trueOrFalse [questions]="preguntas"></app-trueOrFalse>
```